# tail-ing a filename that is a date

Tags: bash, command-line, date, tail

I am creating a logfile from kermit named the current date (which is in the format of DD MMM YYYY - which can not be changed AFAIK), and using the file name as today's date.

I then have a Bash script to read the file and I want to `tail -n1` the file.

if I do

```
    filename=$(date +%d\ %b\ %Y) && echo $filename
```

I get

```
    23 Feb 2015
```

which is what I want and expect. However if I then do

```
    filename=$(date +%d\ %b\ %Y) && tail -n1 $filename
```

I get

```
    tail: cannot open `23' for reading: No such file or directory
    tail: cannot open `Feb' for reading: No such file or directory
    tail: cannot open `2015' for reading: No such file or directory
```

I am not sure what is causing this, probably down to the the way I have string formatted I guess since I get the same if I use `tail` or `cat`?

Comment: It is better to ask a direct question like "What causes `tail` to give these errors and how do I solve this?" than to ask for me specifically to offer assistance (I'm not always online, nor do I know everything).

Answer (score 1):

Double-quote your variables. Double-quote your variables. Double-quote your variables.

```
filename=$(date +'%d %b %Y') && tail -n1 "$filename"
```

Comment: Many thanks! - it worked perfectly !! - and thanks for the explanation! - will try to remember in future!

Comment: ITYM **ＤＯＵＢＬＥ－ＱＵＯＴＥ  ＹＯＵＲ  ＶＡＲＩＡＢＬＥＳ！**